# Trim Text with "..." if it is too long

Tags: css

I have a div of certain size. Now whenever data is coming to that div from database, the excess length of the text is coming down as wrap text (like MS Excel). I want it to be in one line and obviously within the div. End the line with "..."

Can anyone help me to do so using css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question could be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I have done that... I know and that much of sense I have...Thanks again for your time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-wrap: nowrap;
```

Comment: Those and `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Thanks !! But it is showing as same as previous...Cleaned the cache...same repetition...

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

It will render '...' if it is too long.

Reference: **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp**

**Edit:** Thanks to AndyM's comment, you can also use `white-space:nowrap` to handle white spaces `overflow:hidden` to prevent text overflow.

Comment: You'll also need `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` for this to work.